# In standard isolated lab

Tags: knowledge

(Skip this story, that is not part of question, only might be helpful. Sorry for bad English, you can correct things, no stego this time.)
Robot Dan (world smartest vacuum cleaner) and I went to the old isolated lab. It was standard time traveling lab, so kind of cool. However system of time traveling was complicated in calculation date you wanted, because of isotopes it has in it. On machine was big display with simple question: "Centuries?" but on keyboard below were no numbers, just another displays with some pictures, some with puzzles. International organisation for peace made sure to "time travel must be complicated". "Where you wanna go, master?" said robot Dan. I noticed something in my pocket - "What about date on that memorial coin I showed you earlier?" Dan stopped for a moment: "No problem to calculate!" And started to mash symbols. First with guy with laurel on his head (with name Caesar as description), then some Pope. Display changed to: "Years?" and Dan just mashed display with new sofa brand De Lux x, and display changed to: "Months?" Dan mashed symbol with some orchestra and another one with some singers. Not sure what that means, but it even changed years, don't know why. Last symbol for "days?" was with 6 people holding each other with kindness. Dan saw my confused face and said: "Tolerance of course." That puzzled me even more. But suddenly we were somewhere else - or better - sometime else. It was street in London (?) and nothing happened. Only some old guy said (or grumbled?): "Today is stupidest day of this country." I picked up a newspapers from ground (like they do in movies when they time travel) and found what I was looking for.

**TLDR:**
Find: YYyy-MM-dd (centuries,years-months-days) If you find something overflowing - just add it to higher attribute (eg 25 months = 2 years + 1 month).
**YY** = Current difference between Caesar and Pope Gregory in days  (add 1, since we are currently in future, nothing else changed)
**yy** = sofa De LuX X
**MM** = Difference between London Classical Players and Lithuanian Chamber Orchestra.
(might depend on big musical instrument they have, so I don't care if any player is sick or not. Maybe Rudolf or Heinrich could help you with this one.)
**dd** = Only day in november, when you have to be tolerant to each other. (not that you can't be tolerant any other day…)

And finally it was on **1st day of week**. What date it was?

Edit1:

> Forgot to mention what year we are in future, which would change YY, but difference would be only "add 1"

Hint 0:

> [Some random map](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/35hb3a/first_day_of_the_week_in_different_countries/) and 1st day of week means, that is not necessary exactly "dd", but most likely few days earlier.

Comment: Btw Inspired by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Fortress

Comment: Should there be a wordplay tag?

Comment: @Talal_Sharaa I'm never sure about tags, maybe "story" tag. There is just no "A=1" etc, so maybe add it too, if u like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full answer:

YY:

> **14** "According to the new edit"
>  The difference between a julian calendar and a gregorian calendar currently is 13.

yy:

> **570**
>  Sofa De LuX X the capitalized letters are roman numerals 
>  DLXX = 570

MM: thanks @Gareth McCaughan♦ for your help

> 1- The text says "heinrich or rudolf" which points to heinrich rudolf hertz
>  2-" might depend on big musical instrument they have"
>  Which points to a Piano
>  So combining the 2 together 
>  We know that the answer to the clue is the difference between which pitch   LCP and LCO tuned their piano to.
>
>  The LCP tuned their piano to A=430Hz
>  And LCO tuned their piano to                A= 444Hz
>  Note that in Europe the frequency of A4
>  commonly varies between 440 Hz and 444 Hz
>  So the answer for the clue is 14 which is more than 12, so the years will increase by 1 and...
>
>  MM is **02**

DD:

> **15**
>  16th of November is the international day of tolerance 
>  And it was tuesday that year... But both the title & text indicates the first day of week is monday...

So the answer is:

> **1971 02 15**
>
>  Which is the [Decimal day](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_Day)
>  And probably the old guy was angry because it's the day that the United Kingdom and the Republic of Ireland decimalised their currencies.

P.s: the meaning of the title..

> According to international standard ISO 8601, Monday is the first day of the week.

Comment: yy - not Exedous, but simple reference to Caesar again. And it is bigger number.

Comment: forgot to mention what year we are in future, just add to YY+1. But so far so good.

Comment: Edited it, I hope it's right now

Comment: Yea, you are close.

Comment: I deduced the month but still trying to support it with the meaning of the clue...

Comment: First day of week could be sunday if we are in something like USA, not Europe :) But no, it is not necessary 16th, it will be just first day of given week, so somewhere between 09 and 16. There are also few hints in Title and text.

Comment: I'm betting the day is 1971-02-15 and the coin is from the United Kingdom. But I have no idea what's going on with the orchestras. There are plenty of Heinrichs and a few Rudolfs in classical music but so far I'm failing to find an obvious one-of-each that go together. Heinrich Schiff was a cellist ("big musical instrument") but doesn't have any obvious association with either of those ensembles.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Maybe they are not 2 people

Comment: ... Oh. I actually wondered about that but didn't pursue it. Let me check the relevant numbers.

Comment: Hmph. Not having much luck here. Norrington seems to have liked 430 for Mozart but I'd guess the LCP used 415 sometimes and 440 sometimes too. Can't find anything specific about Lithuania or the LCO. The concert hall they're most associated with (I think) got a new organ in 1963 which I assume was 440. It seems like we're looking for a month value of 14 and I'm not seeing any differences of 14 here. But probably I'm being dim.

Comment: Ah, wait. http://members.aon.at/fnistl/page3.html says 444 for LCO. That with 430 for LCP will do it.

Comment: @Talal_Sharaa If the foregoing makes sense to you, feel free to add the relevant stuff to complete your answer. Or I can edit it in myself; or, if you prefer, I can make an answer of my own (but that might be awkward because Jan might feel obliged to give it the checkmark and you did much more of the work than I did).

Comment: (In fact the same page explicitly says 430 for the LCP too, which I hadn't noticed when I wrote the comment two up from here.)

Comment: Yeah Actually I just Arrived at the same conclusion and was searching for it, I will add it to my answer and give the credit to you, if it's okay?

Comment: Fine with me. If you got there independently, feel free not to credit me.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan thanks a lot,  I updated my answer, I'll be glad to edit anything that needs to be clearer.

Comment: Btw ISO 16:  classical pitch is 430 Hz, and  concert pitch is between 440-444, so u had only 4 possibilities if u could not find exact date. Btw hints were: Coin, London, even Romans slightly (Decimation)